# Sending/Receiving Message to Another URL or Tab in VUE

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, vuejs2, event-handling

I've created a simple code example in VUE where I'm sending and receiving messages. The example of the code is on CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wc1mc and click `Go To Board` some random URL is generated eg.`https://wc1mc.csb.app/board/100`. I'm struggling with sending the message to another browser tab. My solution works in the same tab but not across the tabs. Now what I would like to do:

1. Open this URL `https://wc1mc.csb.app/board/100` in two browser tabs
2. Open another URL eg. `https://wc1mc.csb.app/board/50` in the third tab
3. In the tab `https://wc1mc.csb.app/board/100` click button `Update`
4. Both tabs with ending `100` should show `Received: 100` and the tab `50` should not be updated

I would like to use messages as in the future sender and receiver might be on a different domain. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are we talking multiple users around multiple locations and networks or only across one user on one machine/location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Broadcast Channel API allows basic communication between browsing contexts (that is, windows, tabs, frames, or iframes) and workers on the same origin.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Broadcast_Channel_API